# Recode algorithm QGIS GRASS

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, reclassify

I am trying to reclassify a slope (elevation) raster to a scale from 1 to 10 using QGIS GRASS `r.recode` with the following algorithm:

`input_value_low:input_value_high:1:10`

Unfortunately it will generate a layer with the scale from 1 to 9 and I have no clue why. 
Any ideas?!

Comment: Does input_value_low:input_value_high:1:11 do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does. But I still don`t know why